# Are salt substitutes good alternatives to sodium chloride?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry, medicinal-chemistry

I bought a low salt Ketchup from Heinz and it says it uses ‘ALSOSALT’ substitute (potassium chloride). It says it does have 5 mg of sodium. Is potassium chloride (with possible additives) a good alternative to sodium chloride and does it not cause problems for the heart or general health?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small quantities of potassium are fine. Windsor Salt of Canada makes a 50% blend of sodium chloride and potassium chloride called Half Salt. You could use it like regular salt, although it would be good to decrease the amount you use.

Nerve impairment and muscle function are affected from too much potassium.

Comment: That's the problem right there.  Someone who needs to cut down on salt does it usually because of reduced kidney function.  That demographics is *at high risk* from excess potassium intake.